# Using a combined Insert & Edit form vs seperate, what is best practice?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listview, insert, edit

I have an asp.net listview to display records. I then use jquery to add/edit records by displaying a form. The form will look the same whether inserting/editing but certain things will change e.g. on open I will clear all fields for add, and populate for edit. I will change button from Update to Add etc.

My question is - it feels wrong to be coding ifs into javascript to check if it is an insert or edit action. But then again it feels wrong to duplicate most of the functinality by having a separate form.
Is there a standard or best practice way of doing this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't feel there's anything wrong using the same form. This way, it will save you from writing extra markup/html. I personally do that alot.